# Generate a DOM Document with Thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I am currently working on an existing thymeleaf 3.0 to project which transform between different XML message formats using custom Processors.

Everything is working, but i need to access the generated XML as a DOM Document after thymeleaf processing.

The current code feeds a DOM Document to the 'TemplateEngine.process()' method which returns the finished document as String and there are no other methods which would allow another form of return value (as far as I can see). So I am afterwards using a DOM parser again - a step I would like to avoid.

How can i achieve this?

edit: simple code example

```
String templateName = "template name";
TemplateEngine templateEngine = getTemplateEngine();
Context context = new Context();
String createdDocumentString = templateEngine.process(templateName, context);
Document createdDocument = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(thymeleafDocumentString)));
```

and i would like to skip the last step - getting the document directly from thymeleaf because i believe somewhere during processing it is already in this form

Comment: Can you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question as formatted text, (e.g. code, templates, inputs, expected outputs)?

Comment: unfortunately not right now, will try to provide something in the coming days

Comment: added a simplified example now - hope you can help me, @andrewjames

Comment: Thank you for the update, but this isn't a minimal reproducible example. The best advice I can give you, based on your updated question is: Dont use Thymeleaf. Use an XML parser. Or stick with what you already have, if it works. Sorry I can't be of more help.